# Unable to debug in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using `Xcode 4.6.x` and the iPad iOS version is `6.1.3`. I have added the device in Provisioning Profile. But when i connect it does not allow me to debug.

I have checked the Base SDK, it is `6.1` and Deployment Target is `6.1`. I have tried to switch off and restart the iPad, but it's not working yet.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You need to assign code sign identity with developer Certificate. otherwise it will not work.

Comment: arman is correct or if u r using certificate type distribution then it must be checked with addhoc

Comment: Restart. Always a good thing to do when dealing with The Beast That Is Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Check it once again the device id, add to provisioning profile.
Remove old provisioning profile. 
Remove the app from the device. and remove form DerivedData folder also
Than add latest provisioning profile.
Than try to debug hopefully its work.

Answer (score 0):

First clean your project [alt + clean] i.e. Clean Build Folder, Quit xCode, then remove app from your device.
Now build project and run. Delete all data from Derived Data folder. Also make sure you are not using distribution profile.

Hopefully this will work.